# When to use return statements in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have some python code and I want to convert it to scala.

**Python code:**

```py
def temp(x):
    if(x == 5):
        return "equal to 5" //basically, this would be a guard clause in a real world example
    // Maybe do some processing
    return "not equal to 5"

print(temp(5)) //prints "equal to 5"
print(temp(6)) //prints "not equal to 5"
```

I create a scala worksheet and try to translate it line by line but the result is not the same.

**Scala code:**

```scala
object test {
  def temp(x: Int): String = {
    if (x == 5)
      "equal to 5"
    "not equal to 5"
  }                                               //> temp: (x: Int)String

  temp(5)                                         //> res0: String = not equal to 5
  temp(6)                                         //> res1: String = not equal to 5
}
```

I removed the keyword `return` because I read that it is not required in scala, but apparently, I cannot remove it in this context. I get the correct result if I do not remove the keyword `return`.

Why cannot I remove it in this context? Is there some other way to use guard clauses in scala? Or is there something else that is causing the unexpected output?

Comment: "never", if you can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is to understand in Scala if-else **expressions** are just that - **expressions**, not control structures. Hence

```
if (x == 5) "equal to 5"
```

does not mean

*"if x equals five, then return five",*

instead it means something like

*"if x equals five, then evaluate this expression to five, otherwise evaluate to uknown value."*

In fact we could write

```
val v: Any = if (x == 5) "equal to 5"
```

Note how the type of `v` is `Any`, because we have not provided the `else` part of the expression, so the best compiler can do is deduce `Any` type. Providing else clause we have

```
val v: String = if (x == 5) "equal to 5" else "not equal to 5"
```

where we see `v` is now nicely typed to `String` as required. Now in Scala if we put an expression as the **last** expression in the block, then this becomes the return value of the function. Thus

```
def temp(x: Int): String = {
  if (x == 5)
    "equal to 5"
  "not equal to 5"
}
```

is equivalent to

```
def temp(x: Int): String = {
  val v1: Any = if (x == 5) "equal to 5"
  // do nothing with v1

  val v2: String = "not equal to 5"
  return v2
}
```

where we see `temp` will always return just `v2`. Instead we should write simply

```
def temp(x: Int): String =
  if (x == 5) "equal to 5" else "not equal to 5"
```

We could say if-else expression acts as a traditional control structure only when it is the last expression in the block.

---

More formally, in [conditional expression](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#conditional-expressions) `if (1) 2 else 3`

- The type of the conditional expression is the *weak least upper bound* of the types of `2` and `3`
- `if (1) 2` is evaluated as if it was `if (1) 2 else ()`.

where `()` value has `Unit` type which is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58259448/5205022).