# Trying to understand if statements in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am trying to understand why my code doesn't work! I am trying to solve the classic balance parentheses problem and Im getting a no such element on my third if statement which doesn't make sense to me because I thought my second if statement would avoid that case but I dont think my second if statement is returning?

```
  def balance(chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {
    def check(left: Int,right: List[Char]): Boolean = {
      if (left < 0) false
      if (right.isEmpty) left == 0
      if (right.head == ')') check(left + 1, right.tail)
      else check(left - 1, right.tail)
    }
    check(0,chars.filter(x => (x == ')') || (x == '(')))
  }
```

Comment: Are you really getting a null pointer exception? Or No Such Element exception? we don't have nulls in Scala, I don't know of any case where the standard lib would throw a null pointer

Comment: `if`...`else if` ... `else if` ... `else` ...

Comment: see jwvh's comment or use `return false` ... `return left == 0`

Comment: @MikhailIonkin Scala also highly discourage the return statements afaik :) Rob wrote a detailed blog post on why they should be avoided https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html

Comment: thanks. But I never use `return` in cases like in the link. IMHO, in some cases `return` make code more clear. In Scala code (on github) `return` used very rarely, but used:
https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/6b4d32c3f518d21a798e8d3cf4a8c35866afa8e2/src/scaladoc/scala/tools/nsc/doc/html/SyntaxHigh.scala

Comment: @Mikhaillonkin IMHO a return never makes the code readable. And taking into account that it may have unexpected behaviours I would never use it. Ironically the standard library implementation shouldn't be used as an example on how to program in Scala. It is written in a very discouraged imperative style just for the sake of performance. The STD lib has a good argument for be in that way, but day to day Scala code does not. Also, IMHO, encouraging bad practices to beginners is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on my comment. I don't believe that you are actually getting a Null Pointer exception. Scala doesn't encourage the use of nulls and I don't know of any case where the standard library will return a null. Nulls are encapsulated by Option.None in Scala (or see upcoming [explicit nulls](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/explicit-nulls.html) in Scala 3)  and even when you are integrating with a Java library, it is recommended that you wrap the null behavior in an option.

That being said, under the assumption that you are getting a `No Such Element Exception` in reality, let's look at you code.

**Understanding the return behavior in Scala**

A Scala function will take the last value in it's body as it's return value. In your case it is this block

```
if (right.head == ')') check(left + 1, right.tail)
else check(left - 1, right.tail)
```

Since the previous `if` blocks are not conditionally linked together **all 3 of them** will be evaluated. Even if one of the first two evaluates the true, Scala will NOT return and continue to evaluate because it sees more code in the function body it has not computed yet.

So in this case even if the second condition is true, the third one still gets evaluated.

Use the full ternary syntax and add else

```
  if (left < 0) false else
  if (right.isEmpty) left == 0 else 
  if (right.head == ')') check(left + 1, right.tail)
  else check(left - 1, right.tail)
```

More on ternary syntax [here](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-ternary-operator-syntax)

Comment: Scala HAS null, but using null (commonly) is bad practice. It's true, because Java has null, and Scala can use Java libraries. Also you can init null variable in Scala code.

Comment: @MikhailIonkin you are correct, fixing the answer thank you. Just looked up and there is indeed a null in the stdlib

Comment: Thank you! this makes a lot of sense!

Comment: Is it better form to use else's or returns after every if? or should I be using something else entirely?

Comment: @DezYalom As I have mentioned in the comments above, I highly highly discourage you from using returns. They dont always work as expected and under the hood they are very different from the return that you have come to know from other languages. There is a blog post that you can read about this here: https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html See Luis' comment above for more info as well. ```if else``` here is the correct way of doing this. It allows the reader to have linear understanding of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Let us desugar `check` definition a little bit:

```
def check(...) = 
{
  if (left < 0) false else ();                              // expression 1

  if (right.isEmpty) left == 0 else ();                     // expression 2

  return if (right.head == ')') check(...) else check(...); // expression 3 (last expression)
}
```

Note how the semicolons `;` make it clear we have three separate expressions in the expression block, and only the last one is passed to `return`. Now the two key concepts to understand are

- conditional expressions `if (1) 2 else 3` are first-class **values** (and [not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58258894/5205022) control statements)
- the "returned" value of the whole block expression is only the value of the **last expression** in the block

Hence to fix the issue, as suggested by others, we need to connect the three separate expressions into a **single** expression of the form `if...else if ... else if ... else`.